# boost path when cross compiling

Tags: boost, cross-compiling, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When cross-compiling for the Nao in http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling should the boost path be set to the system's boost directory (i.e. /usr) or to some directory local to the location of the cross-compilation (i.e. /media/external/ros/electric/ros...)?  If the latter, where should I be setting the path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12572/boost-path-when-cross-compiling/) by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alternatively, you could set the [`ROS_BOOST_ROOT`](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_BOOST_ROOT) and `ROS_BOOST_VERSION` environment variables:

```
// for naoqi 1.10.xx
export ROS_BOOST_ROOT="${CTC_DIR}/staging/geode-linux/usr"    
export ROS_BOOST_VERSION="1.38.0"

// for naoqi 1.12
export ROS_BOOST_ROOT="${CTC_DIR}/sysroot/usr"
export ROS_BOOST_VERSION="1.45.0"
```

Make sure that the version variable matches the boost library version in your cross-compilation toolchain and that

```
rosboost-cfg --lib_dir
```

actually returns the correct directory containing the boost libraries.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Osswald](https://answers.ros.org/users/1042/stefan-osswald/) with karma: 281 on 2012-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're cross compiling you absolutely don't want to use your natively compiled boost directories - i.e. do not use /usr!

You need to look for where your cross compiled boost libs are actually installed - usually this will be inside your toolchain. I notice from the wiki page you link to the instructions:

```
cp -r $CTC_USR_DIR/lib/libboost* $TARGETDIR/libs/
```

The short of it - $TARGETDIR/libs should be what he's attaching to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in setup.sh to find boosts's libs. Just make sure it's empty to begin with (notice the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= # just to be sure` just above) otherwise it will pick up your native libs.
Is there another variable you are trying to set to help with boost?

Actually, hacking it this way is a bit ugly - cmake would be much better here.

For more details:

If you want to be absolutely sure you have the libs, have a look in `$TARGETDIR/libs/`. You should see libboost*.so in there. You can actually check that they're cross compiled by running file on the command - e.g. in my arm toolchain:

```
file libexpat.so.0.1.0
libexpat.so.0.1.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4